# Laraver выборка из БД

Tags: laravel, eloquent

В Laravel новичек. Делаю выборку одного поля из БД. Как можно вывести выбранную запись без foreach?

```
$imei = \Models\Device::select('imei')->where('md2', $_POST['md2'])->get();
```

Comment: Я не понимаю суть вопроса. `md2` уникальное поле? Вы получаете только 1 строку этим запросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если get(), то в $imei будет массив. Соответственно, $imei[0]->imei.
Если поле одно, то лучше использовать first() вместо get() `$imei = \Models\Device::select('imei')->where('md2', $_POST['md2'])->first();`- тогда значение будет доступно через $imei->imei.

$_POST в запросе не есть хорошо. Обрабатывайте данное значение, во избежании инъекций